# What tool should I use to decompile Java byte code to Java source code?

Tags: java, jvm, decompiling

If you had to decompile java byte code into Java source code, what tool would you use?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the many hits given by Google? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+decompiler

Comment: This kind of questions are outside the scope of this site. I don't know why people upvote this.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/

The tool is called JAD

Instructions here:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Decompiling_Java_bytecode

Answer (score 1):

you can use [cavaj](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://download.cnet.com/Cavaj-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10071619.html&ei=qYaKUafeMMnprQemnYDwCA&usg=AFQjCNGJTimYX_tlafuqamydNgLn4t8KHQ&bvm=bv.46226182,d.bmk) or [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-gui) do decompile .class to java code